# Problem with AJAX when send JSON to PHP, ¿ParseError?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this problem

My Ajax request:

```
 function test(){
        
        const json = {"name" : {"name" : "test", "other" : 4} };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/print.php",
            data: {m:json, mm:"5"},
            dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            cache: false,
            success: function(neu){
                console.log(neu.status);
            },
            error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        }).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        });

  }
```

My PHP (print.php)

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  $ticket = $_POST['m'];
  // if remove this, print "ok" "ok" and i don't know why, never had problem with that
  $connector = new NetworkPrintConnector("192.168.1.5",9100);
  $printer = new Printer($connector);
  //
  $response['status'] = "ok";
  echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

When i make test(); on console
Return : "ok" 1 time , no errors (always good)

But when i make test();test(); at the same time on console...
Return :  "ok" only 1 time, when it should be "ok" "ok" without errors

```
ok
parsererror
index.php:8408 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at n.parseJSON (jquery.js?v=270:4:5309)
at vc (jquery.js?v=270:4:7397)
at x (jquery.js?v=270:4:10802)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js?v=270:4:14767)
index.php:8411 parsererror
index.php:8412 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at n.parseJSON (jquery.js?v=270:4:5309)
at vc (jquery.js?v=270:4:7397)
at x (jquery.js?v=270:4:10802)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js?v=270:4:14767)
```

jquery.js is just jquery 2.1.4 library.

I tried:
Quit `dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`, and put `dataType: 'json'`,
Without dataType,
With and Without  : `header('Content-type: application/json');` on PHP..

Comment: The second response is being returned in HTML or XML format - I would assume it's an error message. To debug AJAX requests, open the network tab of devtools and investigate from there

Comment: `dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` — That's not a valid value for `dataType`. You seem to have confused it for `contentType` (which would also be wrong since the top level of data you are sending is not encoded as JSON).

Comment: `const json = {"` means it is not JSON.

Comment: Oh, so how can send the JSON? sorry for the question. dataType: 'json' not works

Comment: @nacho1111 — Why do you want to send the data as JSON? Your server side code isn't set up to process JSON.

Comment: For more details about evolutionxbx's comment about it not being JSON, see https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @Quentin, because the data that i need to send is more complex that "json" test variable. So much info that is more simple to me send with json

Comment: @Quentin thanks for "benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json ", now i think different. But with JSON.stringify() and json_decode in php not working. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: As noted above `Unexpected token <` means the response is HTML (most likely).  What *is* that response when you look in the network tab?

Comment: You could also add `dataType: "text"` to your request, then change to `success: function(data) { console.log(data); }` - in your "ok" state, it will be a json *string*, in your not-ok state, it will be an html-*string*.

Comment: i will try. thanks!. i will comment the response in a few minutes

Comment: Looking closer at where the error might occur (ie within your php) - it could be that `NetworkPrintConnector` has DDOS protection so fails when two requests are made too closely together.  The HTML response may tell you what the error is, but may just be "500 server error" - in which case you'll need to debug your code and/or wrap the NetworkPrintConnector / Printer code in a try-catch (or equiavalent)

Comment: @freedomn-m YES!! Awesome ! that was the error. I Use WindowsPrintConnector and works perfect. Thanks so much!